# PostgreSQL: get time windows where a column value changes between two states

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have the following informations which might help to understand what my source is and probably someone can give me a hint into the right direction so I get the result I expect.

**Database source:**

```
+-------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------+
| time                          | state       | entity_id                                   |
|-------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------|
| 2020-11-21 22:08:30.697555+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-21 22:09:09.653517+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-21 22:10:10.100732+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-21 23:00:19.579074+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-21 23:50:28.929034+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 00:40:36.844207+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 01:30:46.625915+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 02:20:55.728533+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 03:11:04.69336+00  | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 04:51:25.005591+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 05:41:35.027022+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 08:28:55.070897+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 08:28:55.071764+00 | on          | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 09:16:44.351438+00 | on          | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 09:16:44.353371+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 10:06:58.250254+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 10:57:07.857459+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 11:47:17.45144+00  | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 12:37:25.463751+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 13:27:34.908661+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:17:41.562764+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:38:02.050999+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:38:02.052771+00 | on          | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:38:48.250308+00 | on          | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:38:48.251718+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 15:29:03.709037+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 16:19:13.114918+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 17:09:21.919555+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 17:59:29.769124+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 18:49:38.585074+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 19:00:22.724232+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 19:01:05.545263+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 21:20:01.554877+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:00:39.663975+00 | unavailable | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:00:42.898337+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:01:23.566599+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:10:08.907583+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:32:17.391582+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 22:32:56.633317+00 | off         | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
```

**Current Query (which gives me duplications):**

```sql
SELECT
    q1.start,
    q2.stop,
    q1.entity_id AS entity
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT time as start,
        entity_id
    FROM ltss 
    WHERE 
        entity_id LIKE 'binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact'
        AND state = 'on'
    ORDER BY start ASC
    ) q1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        entity_id, 
        time as stop,
        state
    FROM ltss
    WHERE state = 'off'
    ORDER BY time ASC
) q2 ON (q1.entity_id = q2.entity_id AND q2.stop > q1.start)
ORDER BY q1.start
```

I want receive all ranges where a value "on" is followed by an "off".

As there are multiple entries for "on" and "off" (as some other column has changed), I want the most recent "on" but the earliest "off".

All other "on" values between two "on" and "off" states must be omitted aswell as any "off" state which do not have a preceding "on" value.

In case there is no recent "off" value available (because the state "off" is not yet reached), I'd like to get the row but with `null` for `stop`.

Hopefully, the crowd can help me here.

**Thanks in advance!**

**Edit:** As requested, this is the output I'd expect from the data provided earlier in this post.

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| start                         | end                           | entity_id                                   |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| 2020-11-22 08:28:55.071764+00 | 2020-11-22 09:16:44.353371+00 | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
| 2020-11-22 14:38:02.052771+00 | 2020-11-22 14:38:48.251718+00 | binary_sensor.bedroom_double_window_contact |
```

Comment: Please post, in the question, the desired output for the sample data supplied.

Comment: agree with @Belayer, we need your desired output example. I think i can help here